# How Gosub is supposed to work?

Tags: autohotkey

Please, execute the following script in AutoHotkey:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Event  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

#Persistent

Gosub, Mylabel
Return

MsgBox, It worked!

MyLabel:
Sleep, 1000
Return
```

I would expect it to call `MyLabel`, that is, waiting 1 second, and then to pop up the message box.

But it does not.

What am I missing in the `Gosub` functioning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `return` at the line following the `gosub` call.

take it out, it halts the script.

Like this:

```
(1) Gosub, Mylabel
; Return

(2) MsgBox, It worked!

(3) MyLabel:
(4) Sleep, 1000
(5) Return
```

Basically, after the `Gosub` line the code behind *Mylabel* is started.
Once it reaches a `return` it jumps back and continues with the line after `Gosub`.

The execution order here is (1), jump to label (3),run command (4), run return (5) because the gosub was issued earlier this jumps to line after (1), run (2) and you see the message. Afterwards the code continues passing the label at (3) again, running (4) again and this time return at (5) stops the script completely.

Comment: I still do not understand: if «Once it reaches a `return` it jumps back and continues with the line after `Gosub`», isn't it supposed to display the message box? `MyLabel` was already executed...

Comment: I edited it to explain what happens more clearly. The ";" before Return marks it as comment so it doesn't run.

Comment: Ok, I am going to make some experiments with `Gosub` following your advices, then I'll be back here to accept your answer :) Thank you!

Comment: A fast question on the same topic: can you confirm that, if `MyLabel` does take long to run (like minutes), `Gosub` actually waits for `MyLabel` to finish before proceeding with the rest of the code? I mean: it is supposed to work in that way, correct?

Comment: Correct. All the code after MyLabel will be executed fully. The code needs to reach a `return` line to jump back. (Not sure if reaching the last line of code also counts as return...)

Comment: According to my trials, I think it doesn't count as `Return`.